# Amazon MWS Error When Subitting _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_ Feed

Tags: amazon-mws

I am getting the following error:

```
<Result>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
<ResultMessageCode>25</ResultMessageCode>
<ResultDescription>We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.</ResultDescription>
```

The XML that I submitted is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>**REMOVED**</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderFulfillment>
      <MerchantOrderID>ORD-20000018</MerchantOrderID>
      <MerchantFulfillmentID>DEL-50000018</MerchantFulfillmentID>
      <FulfillmentDate>2014-10-08T14:55:00+00:00</FulfillmentDate>
      <FulfillmentData>
        <CarrierCode>Royal Mail</CarrierCode>
        <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
        <ShipperTrackingNumber>KF95809XXXGB</ShipperTrackingNumber>
      </FulfillmentData>
      <Item>
        <MerchantOrderItemID>1013</MerchantOrderItemID>
        <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>22</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      </Item>
    </OrderFulfillment>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Could you let me know where I could be going wrong, I double checked the element names with the xsd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [OrderFulfillment.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/OrderFulfillment.xsd) schema, `MerchantFulfillmentID` is of type [`IDNumber`](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/amzn-base.xsd), which is derived from the type `xsd:positiveInteger`. The [amzn-base.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/amzn-base.xsd) also specifies a regular expression constraint of `<xsd:pattern value="\d{1,20}"/>` for `IDNumber`. So try changing your first `MerchantFulfillmentID` to an integer (which by the way doesn't match your second `MerchantFulfillmentID` under `Item` at the moment).

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved the issue, can't believe I missed that. As for the "second" MerchantFulfillmentID that element is actually MerchantFulfillmentItemID which should be a different value. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helps. Can I get an upvote on the answer too, if you don't mind? Thanks! :)